# Alt code with letter + not working

Tags: alt-code

I can't enter Unicode characters that have a letter e.g. **U-255C** which is ╜

I have seen people do this by doing the following steps:

Hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> →
Type + (on the Number pad) → Type 255C → let go of <kbd>Alt</kbd>

But its not working on my computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows does support Unicode sequences, but you'll need to make an adjustment [as described on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_code):

> [...] a user must set or create the registry key `HKCU\Control Panel\Input
>   Method\EnableHexNumpad` with type `REG_SZ` to value `1` and reboot (logging
>   out and logging back in is sufficient). Once the registry key is set,
>   the following method can be used to enter Unicode codepoints:
>
> Hold Alt and type the + key on the numeric keypad, then type the hexadecimal number (using the numeric keypad for digits 0-9 and the
>   normal keys for a-f), then release Alt.
>
> For example, Alt++11b will produce "ě" (e with caron).

Comment: alt+189 on my computer is the ¢ character. extended Ascii doesnt seem to match with all characters. Which is why i was trying to use the Unicode variant but it has a letter in it

Comment: thanks the Registry key did the trick. i can now type ╜. i get that the ASCII code is 189 but my machine seems to be doing Unicode. if you remove the first line or edit it to say Ascii = Alt189 vs Unicode = Alt+255C or something like that ill accept the answer

Comment: @Dangas56 Updated

Comment: @OuroborusThanks, i dont have enough rep to up the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is ancient news, but for anyone else in this situation I just wanted to add this link... [Windows registry fix](https://scriptsource.org/cms/scripts/page.php?item_id=entry_detail&uid=tmhr3s5nsc)
It's a nifty little download created by Bob Hallissy and released under [The Creative Commons • Attribution ShareAlike](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)
For those of us that suffer cold sweats by the thought of making manual adjustments to the registry this is a lifesaver.
Download and install - with a size of 1kb I highly doubt it has the room to carry any unwanted "bugs"...